How to encrypt a directory so that no one can access even when mounted?
In Ubuntu 22.04, I use EncFS to mount a folder (directory) for myself which includes my sensitive data. Every time the system is booted, I mount it manually not to store the password anywhere in the system, not to be discovered by anyone. Besides, I'm sure that even root may not access my files in my system at company. I may give them the root password without being worried. The directory may be mounted at the same time, but even root can't see my files. They may not even see the directory and find that it's there. This is what I can't reach with LUKS (whole disk encryption) or eCryptfs. They can't work this way, but EncFS can. So it's ideal, but the overhead is very high. CPU usage, hard disk read and write and slowness of copy operations bother me.
Please let me know whether there's a better solution which work like EncFS this way. I need others even root can't access the directory at the same time it's mounted and is accessible for me who know the password.
It's okay if the solution includes the whole disk encryption, because it's the second hard disk in my system and is not going to be the boot disk.

Indeed EncFS has caused me not to use fastness of ext4! Besides, the max path is reduced with EncFS.

:Please let me know whether there's a better solution which work like EncFS this way"   I doubt it. EncFS is tool to use  "I'm sure that even root may not access my files in my system at company" if you are not the admin  of that system and you mount it into that system it takes about 5 minutes to set up a method where your password is exposed to the admin once you type it. Everytime you do mount it you need  to change the password.  If the data needs protecting never mount it into a system you do not own.

It's assumed that they're not going to rush with methods like sniffing my password, etc. Besides, every time I'm going to go home, I may shutdown my computer. Even if admins find my system password in my absence, they may not find my folder password.

I would seriously urge you not put your sensitive data on your personal laptop/PC unless the data is securely encrypted by a reliable application (such as GPG, aescrypt, veracrypt etc) first. Even then I should keep those encrypted files on a USB stick and not permanently mounted on your home PC. There are plenty of material on the internet to help you understand the best practices. Try for example: https://www.privacytools.io or tools provided by https://www.eff.org/

Do a Threat/Risk Assessment.  What are you protecting against which threats (and why), and the "cost".
